# useReducer passed with useContext but a child component displays empty state.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, jsx

First, I would thank you for the support.

As new to the ReactJS world, I am trying to complete a concept example of a product store with some filters as checkbox. The idea is that you select a filter, you get displayed the products that have the selected proprety.

Everything works, except that when you refresh the page you get the filters column and  a blank column where products are supposed to appear, even if the `console.log(state)` give back the correct array of objects.

As you click a checkbox (the filters) it render correctly and the products appear.

The [GITHUB LINK](https://github.com/mcdev84/ecommerce_test) for the complete `code`.

Here the component CardProduct that does not display at refresh.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { AppContext }                   from '../../App'
import { Hearty }                       from '../Hearty'
import Star                             from '../Star'
import boiler                           from '../../images/boiler.png'
import Confronta                        from '../Confronta'

const CardProduct = ({ count, setCount }) => {

    const [state, dispatch] = useContext(AppContext)
    console.log('State in CardProduct:', state)

    function returnCardProduct () {
            return (
                state.map((item, i) => {
                    const { brand, descrizione, prezzo, note, stelle } = item
                    return (
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="colcard">
                                <div key={ i } className="card"
                                     style={ { width: 'auto', height: 'auto' } }>
                                    <Hearty/>
                                    <img className="card-img-top" src={ boiler } alt="boiler"/>
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <p className="card-title"> { brand.toUpperCase() }</p>
                                        <h6 className="card-text">{ descrizione }</h6>
                                        <Star stelle={ stelle }/>
                                        <h4> { prezzo }  </h4>
                                        <h5> { note }  </h5>
                                        <Confronta count={ count } setCount={ setCount }/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                }))
    }

    return (

        <div className="container">
            { returnCardProduct() }
        </div>

    )
}
export default CardProduct
```

Here the Filters component

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { AppContext }                      from '../App'


const Filters = () => {

    const [stock, setStock] = useState([])
    const [state,dispatch] = useContext(AppContext)

    function fetchInitialStock () {
        async function fetchStock () {
            let result1 = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/stock').
                then(result1 => result1.json()).
                then(data => setStock(data))
        }
        fetchStock()
        return stock
    }
     useEffect (()=>fetchInitialStock(),[])

console.log( 'initStock' ,stock)
    return (
        <>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">

                    <div className="categories">
                        <p>CATEGORIE</p>
                        <h6>Riscaldamento</h6>
                        <h6>Casa e acqua</h6>
                        <h6>Casa</h6>
                        <h6>Acqua</h6>
                    </div>

                    <div className="scegli">
                        <p>SCEGLI PER</p>

                        <h6><span><input type="checkbox"
                                         name="DISPONIBILI"
                                         onChange={(e)=> {
                                              e.target.checked ? dispatch({ type: 'DISPONIBILI' }) : dispatch({ type:'PREV' })



                                         } }/>
                        </span> Disponibili ({stock.map((item) => item.disponibili  )}) </h6>

                        <h6><span><input type="checkbox"
                                         name="PROMO"
                                         onChange={(e)=> e.target.checked ? dispatch({ type: 'PROMO' }) : dispatch({ type: 'PREV' }) }
                        /> </span>In Promozione ({ stock.map((item) => item.inSconto) }) </h6><br/>

                    </div>

                    <div className="marche">
                        <p>MARCHE</p>

                        <h6><span><input type="checkbox" name="ariston" onChange={(e)=>{
                            e.target.checked
                                ? dispatch({ type: 'ARISTON' })
                                : dispatch({ type: 'PREV' })
                        }}
                        /> </span> Ariston ({stock.map((item)=>item.hasOwnProperty('brand')? item.brand.ariston: null)})</h6>

                        <h6><span><input type="checkbox" name="baxi" onChange={(e)=>{
                            e.target.checked
                                ? dispatch({ type: 'BAXI' })
                                : dispatch({ type: 'PREV' })
                        }}/> </span>Baxi ({stock.map((item)=>item.hasOwnProperty('brand')? item.brand.baxi : null)})</h6><br/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="tipologia">
                        <p>TIPOLOGIA</p>

                        <h6><span><input type="checkbox" name="condensazione" onChange={(e)=>{
                            e.target.checked
                                ? dispatch({ type: 'CONDENSAZIONE' })
                                : dispatch({ type: 'PREV' })
                        }}/> </span> A Condensazione ({stock.map((item)=>item.hasOwnProperty('tipologia')? item.tipologia.condensazione: null)}) </h6>

                        <h6><span><input type="checkbox" name="cameraAperta" onChange={(e)=>{
                            e.target.checked
                                ? dispatch({ type: 'APERTA' })
                                : dispatch({ type: 'PREV' })
                        }}/> </span>Camera Aperta ({ stock.map((item)=>item.hasOwnProperty('tipologia')? item.tipologia.cameraAperta: null) }) </h6>

                        <h6><span><input type="checkbox" name="cameraStagna" onChange={(e)=>{
                            e.target.checked
                                ? dispatch({ type: 'STAGNA' })
                                : dispatch({ type: 'PREV' })
                        }}/> </span>Camera Stagna ({ stock.map((item)=>item.hasOwnProperty('tipologia')? item.tipologia.cameraStagna: null) })</h6><br/>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>

        </>
    )
}

export default Filters
```

..and FINALLY the App()

```
import CardProduct                                        from './components/CardProduct'
import { createContext, useReducer, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Filters  from './components/Filters'
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer'

export const AppContext = createContext()

function App () {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    function setInit (data, array) {
        data.map((item) => array.push(item))
        return array
    }

    /*Function for setting BOILERS from fetch*/
    function fetchInitialBoiler () {
        let initB = []

        async function fetchBoilers () {
            let response = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/boilers').
                then(response => response.json()).
                then(data => setInit(data, initB))
        }

        fetchBoilers()
        return initB
    }

    const initBoilers = fetchInitialBoiler()
    const [prev, setPrev] = useState([])
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initBoilers)

    /* Define the reducer function*/
    function reducer (state, action) {
        let current
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'DISPONIBILI':
                current = []
                current = state.filter((item) => item.disponibile ? item : null)
                setPrev(current)
                return current

            case 'PROMO':
                current = []
                current = state.filter((item) => item.inSconto ? item : null)
                setPrev(current)
                return current

            case 'ARISTON':
                current = []
                current = state.filter(
                    (item) => ((item.hasOwnProperty('brand')) &&
                               (item.brand === 'Ariston'))
                        ? item
                        : null)
                setPrev(current)
                return current

            case 'BAXI':
                current = []
                current = state.filter(
                    (item) => (item.hasOwnProperty('brand')) && (item.brand === 'Baxi')
                        ? item
                        : null)
                setPrev(current)
                return current

            case 'CONDENSAZIONE':
                current = []
                current = state.filter((item) => (item.hasOwnProperty('tipologia')) &&
                                                 (item.tipologia === 'condensazione')
                    ? item
                    : null)
                setPrev(current)
                return current

            case 'APERTA':
                current = []
                current = state.filter((item) => (item.hasOwnProperty('tipologia')) &&
                                                 (item.tipologia === 'camera-aperta')
                    ? item
                    : null)
                setPrev(current)
                return current

            case 'STAGNA':
                current = []
                current = state.filter((item) => (item.hasOwnProperty('tipologia')) &&
                                                 (item.tipologia === 'camera-stagna')
                    ? item
                    : null)
                setPrev(current)
                return current

            case 'PREV':
                current = []
                /*console.log('PREV', prev)*/
                return prev
            default:
                return state
        }
    }




    return (
        <>
            <AppContext.Provider value={ [state, dispatch] }>
                <main>
                    <div className="container">

                        <div className="container">
                            <>
                                <div className="col align-self-start">
                                    <Filters/>
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-9">
                                    <CardProduct count={ count } setCount={ setCount }/>
                                </div>
                            </>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <>
                        <div>
                            <Footer className="footer" count={ count }/>
                        </div>
                    </>
                </main>
            </AppContext.Provider>
        </>
    )
}

export default App
```

--- THANK YOU ---

Comment: UPDATE | Following the advices of sid (thank you) I used inside the component (but I also tried in the App() ) useState hook to fetch() from API and setState in a useEffect hook in the component CardProduct. It render at 1st time, but I cannot find a way to pass the state (const [init,setInit]) to useReducer hook. And it seems wrong, as useReducer do the same thing. Tried to use only useReducer inside the component and but it not take the initialState from fetch() (inside or outside the useEffect). I also tryed the lazy initialization w/no results.

Comment: The main problem is that I cannot get the initialState from fetch() in the useReducer hook inside the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end the problem was to pass the fetch as initialState to useReducer. Searching online I found that is passed throught a dispatch action inside useEffect hook. In this case the useReducer hook is declared with initialState '[]' inside the component. Here the code:

```
  const CardProduct = ({ count, setCount }) => {
    
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, [])
    
        async function initfetch () {
            let response = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/boilers').
                then(response => response.json()).
                then(data => dispatch({
                    type   : 'INITIALIZE',
                    data: data
        }))}
    
        useEffect(() => {
            initfetch()
        }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `initB` is an array declartion which doesn't re-render a React component. Replace it with `useState` to see the updated data after the API call.

```
const [init, setInit] = useState([]);
```

Secondly,

> const initBoilers = fetchInitialBoiler()

you should invoke the `fetchInitialBoiler()` after the document is mounted, with the current approach chances are the API is invoked even before the intial mount.

Invoke it in an `[useEffect][1]` block.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    fetchInitialBoiler() //
    // simply invoke it, since you're not returning anything from the function, there's no need to save the response.
}, [])
```

Your function should set the state in the then/catch block, so that the component tree re-renders in an error case.

```
async function fetchBoilers () {
    let response = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/boilers').
        then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setInit(response))
        .catch(error => setError(error); // state
    }
```

More on Fetch API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Thank you for the advices sid. I will refactor and update about the result.

Comment: hey, did it work?

Comment: Hi sid, and thank you the interest. I found an article in DEV where it suggest to pass the initialState with a dispatch action (action.data in my case) and call it inside useEffetct. And it worked. I let the code in the main post.  